# Just want ask if my way of doing this is right or wrong

Tags: itemize

```
\begin{itemize}
            \item[a$)$]
            \item[b$)$]
            \item[c$)$]
\end{itemize}
```

Will it cause error in the future ?

and should i use `\par` or `\\` to go to next line which should i use ? thanks

Comment: Just use `\item`, no need for `\par` or `\\ `. As a rule of thumb: Never use `\\ ` (outside of tables), there are a few situations where it is the correct thing to do, but those are rare, and a typical beginners' mistake is to use `\\ ` throughout the document.

Comment: @Skillmon then what should i use if i want to start new line not list just paragraph next line ?

Comment: @SoulNoobster If you want to start a new paragraph, you want `\par` (or just leave a line empty, that has the same effect).

Comment: @MarcelKrüger thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want an alphabetic enumeration, I'd suggest using the `enumitem` package. With it you can do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
  \item first
  \item second
  \item third
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: but what should i do if i need to start c) not a) ?

Comment: @SoulNoobster, two cases:  (i) `\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*), start=3]
  \item first
  \item second
  \item third
\end{enumerate}`, (iI)  when you like to continue where you end in the list `enumerate` before it: `\begin{enumerate}
\item First item.
\item Second item.
\end{enumerate}
Some text between successive lists.
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item Third item
\end{enumerate}`. For details see documentation for `enumitem` package.